# How to ssh to xampp-vm on Mac?

Tags: xampp-vm

I am using XAMPP-VM on Mac, I tried to ssh to the VM using the address shown on the xampp manager:

```
192.168.65.2
```

I realized that I don't konw the VM's root password, and any ssh-key info. Is there any way to do this?

I know I can mount the volumn on `/opt/lampp`, it's `~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root` on my machine; but in this way, I don't have permission to write files. If anybody can tell me how to set permission for the mounted file, that will be a great help too.

Answer (score 16):

I changed directory to:

```
cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/ssh
```

There was already an 'id_rsa' and an 'id_rsa.pub' file there and I managed to ssh, as root user, to the IP shown in the XAMPP manager, using this key to use for it to work:

```
ssh -i id_rsa root@192.168.64.2
```

This gave me a root login to the Debian VM:

```
root@debian:~# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
```

Hope this helps.

Richard

Comment: Dear sir, You rock !

Comment: Working on a set of bash scripts for a local-vm to remote-host workflow and this has saved me a ton of time. Thank you.