# Trying to configure SSH access from PhpStorm to XAMPP-vm MAC OS X

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, xampp-vm

I have installed XAMPP-vm 7.4.25-0

I am running all the servers and I can access my site (which I copied into `htdocs`) from a browser. Everything is running fine (Apache & MySQL).

Now I am trying to configure the vm project in PhpStorm, and the first thing that I am not being able to do is to configure the SSH connection in PhpStorm to the VM. I am going to **Configure > Tools > SSH configuration** and I set:

- Host: `localhost`
- Port: `8080`
- User name: `root`
- Password: ???

If I leave password blank, the answer is: "Invalid setting: password is not specified"

If I put `lampp` or any other thing: "...Connection refused..."

This using "**Authentication type: password**". (The other two types, **key pair** and **Open SSH**, I don't know how to parametrize them).

Can someone help me to configure this SSH connection to the XAMPP-vm?

Comment: 8080 is a port forwarded to the HTTP port in the VM, you can't use it for SSH connections. You need to use <vm-ip-address>:22 instead, check out the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121168/8018879

Comment: Thank you very much Eugene. You drove me to the solution. I will post an image with the PhpStorm configuration that finally worked. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eugene Morozov comment, I could find the solution to my question. The image presents the PhpStorm configuration of the SSH connection.

[image: How to configure PhpStorm to SSH connection to a XAMPP virtual machine]